# Compiling multi module maven projects without installing to local repository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, multi-module

I have a compiling (and packaging) problem in my multi-module maven project. Problem occurs when compiling one of two projects which are siblings and included in a parent project and also one is dependent on the other. For simplicity I am sketching project folder structure and `pom.xml` contents here.

`folder structure`

```
-parent
|
|-child1
| |-src
| |  |-main
| |     |-java
| |        |-Child1Class.java
| |-pom.xml
|
|-child2
| |-src
| |  |-main
| |     |-java
| |        |-Child2Class.java
| |-pom.xml
|
|-pom.xml
```

`pom.xml of parent`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>parent</name>
    <modules>
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

`pom.xml of child1`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>child1</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`pom.xml of child2`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>child2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>child2</name>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

As seen, `child2` is a dependency of `child1`. `child1` and `child2` are developed in parallel. So after any source code changes in `child2`, `child1` should be compiled and deployed without any additional operations. But I can't succeed to compile `child1`. After running `mvn compile` command on `child1` this error message is occured:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project child1: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.project:child1: jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example.project:child2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

As I see, maven tries to search local repository for `child2`. If I run `mvn install` command on `parent` project, both projects are added to local repository. Then any attempts to compile `child1` is successful. This seems a solution but it is not convenient. What I want is to compile `child1` while coding `child1` and `child2` without any installation to local repository.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try `mvn compile -pl :child1 -am`, where `-pl` are the projects you'd like to build and `-am` tells maven to build the dependencies of these projects as well if they are part of the multimodule project.

Comment: I didn't know about that advanced option. Seems practical. http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_using_advanced_reactor_options.html

Comment: jeeeez I reviewed 15+ similar questions to find this -am option

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake is to think maven will build the parent when building the child.
It does not.
Try building the parent and maven will automatically guess the build order.

```
C:\parent\child1> mvn clean package
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

C:\parent\child1> cd ..

C:\parent> mvn clean package
[INFO] parent ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.148 s]
[INFO] child2 ............................................. SUCCESS [  1.209 s]
[INFO] child1 ............................................. SUCCESS [  0.073 s]
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Comment: Actually my project is a large project and I simplified to represent here. In real `child1` is a google app engine application and it has app engine maven plugin so I am able to upload it via running this plugin. But it requires `child2` to be located in local reository to build and update. I do not want to package or install parent project each time I run app engine update plugin.

Comment: In that case go in the child2 directory and run `mvn clean install`. Then you can build child1 because child2 is in the local repository. Or if that is not what you want ... just `mvn package` the parent and let maven decide what needs to be compiled.